# select top N records for each entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

I have a `table` like below -

---

```
ID   |  Reported Date                  | Device_ID
-------------------------------------------
1    | 2016-03-09 09:08:32.827         | 1
2    | 2016-03-08 09:08:32.827         | 1
3    | 2016-03-08 09:08:32.827         | 1
4    | 2016-03-10 09:08:32.827         | 2
5    | 2016-03-05 09:08:32.827         | 2
```

Now, i want a `top 1` `row` based on `date column` for each `device_ID`

**Expected Output**

---

```
ID   |  Reported Date                  | Device_ID
-------------------------------------------
1    | 2016-03-09 09:08:32.827         | 1
4    | 2016-03-10 09:08:32.827         | 2
```

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`. i can go and write `Stored Procedure` to handle it but wanted do it with simple query.

****************EDIT**************************

Answer by 'Felix Pamittan' worked well but for 'N' just change it to

```
SELECT
    Id, [Reported Date], Device_ID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Device_ID ORDER BY [ReportedDate] DESC)
    FROM tbl
)t
WHERE Rn >= N
```

He had mentioned this in comment thought to add it to questions so that no body miss it.

Comment: You can use `Group By` along with `MAX` to get what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT
    Id, [Reported Date], Device_ID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Device_ID ORDER BY [ReportedDate] DESC)
    FROM tbl
)t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Comment: Why not use `Group By` and `MAX`. Any particular reason ?

Comment: @CoderofCode Because the OP needs the `Id`

Comment: @AnshulNigam You need to put an alias on the subquery, otherwise it will product a syntax error.

Comment: The 't' is consider as a Derived table.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: so if i want to get top 5 one should replace Rn = 5 at the end?

Comment: @AnshulNigam if you want to get the 5th placer, yes, `Rn = 5` will do. If you want to get the `TOP 5`, it should be `Rn <= 5`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Great it worked like charm, however you can add Rn <= 5 to your answer to help others as questions ask for top(5) also can you explain it a bit it could help people like me who are new to this world

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Also pleae correct me if i am wrong, my understanding is if i use group by it will need an agreegator and here i need more then count?

Comment: @AnshulNigam, if you use `GROUP BY` you need to `JOIN` back to table itself just to get the `Id`. However, if you don't want the `Id`. A simple `SELECT Device_ID, MAX([Reported Date]) AS maxDate
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Device_ID` will do.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: but SELECT Device_ID, MAX([Reported Date]) AS maxDate FROM yourTable GROUP BY Device_ID will just give me max not top 5 rows

Comment: @AnshulNigam oh I'm sorry. Tha's just for top 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use an analytic function, e.g. because your application layer won't allow it, then you can try the following solution which uses a subquery to arrive at the answer:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.maxDate, t1.Device_ID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Device_ID, MAX([Reported Date]) AS maxDate
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Device_ID
) t2
    ON t1.Device_ID = t2.Device_ID AND t1.[Reported Date] = t2.maxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using CTE

```
With DeviceCTE AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Device_ID ORDER BY [Reported Date] DESC) AS Num
 FROM tblname)
 SELECT Id, [Reported Date], Device_ID
 From DeviceCTE
 Where Num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from DEVICE_TABLE D 
where [Reported Date] = (Select Max([Reported Date]) from DEVICE_TABLE where Device_ID = D.Device_ID)
```

should do the trick, assume that "top 1 row based on date column" means that you want to select the latest reported date of each Device_ID ?

As for your title, select top 5 rows of each Device_ID

```
Select * from DEVICE_TABLE D 
where [Reported Date] in (Select top 5 [Reported Date] from DEVICE_TABLE D  where Device_ID =  D.Device_ID)
order by Device_ID, [Reported Date] desc
```

will give you the top 5 latest reports of each device id.
You may want to sort out the top 5 date if your data isn't in order...

Answer (score 0):

Again with no analytic functions you can use CROSS APPLY :

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT,[Reported Date] DateTime , Device_ID INT)
 
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES 
(1,'2016-03-09 09:08:32.827',1),
(2,'2016-03-08 09:08:32.827',1),
(3,'2016-03-08 09:08:32.827',1),
(4,'2016-03-10 09:08:32.827',2),
(5,'2016-03-05 09:08:32.827',2)


SELECT r.*
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Device_ID FROM @tbl ) d
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 * 
                  FROM @tbl t 
                  WHERE d.Device_ID = t.Device_ID ) r
```

Can be easily modified to support N records.

Credits go to wBob answering this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84157/how-to-select-top-10-records-from-each-category)